# Extracting logic out of subclasses

Tags: spring

Currently, I have following model:

```
public abstract class MyClass {

   public abstract boolean validate();

}

public class MyClassImpl1 extends MyClass {

   ....

   public abstract boolean validate() {
      ... // Do something
   }

}

public class MyClassImpl2 extends MyClass {

   ...

   public abstract boolean validate() {
      ... // Do something different
   }

}
```

Somewhere in my code I then use `MyClass`:

```
MyClass myClass = ...;

boolean valid = myClass.validate();
```

Most programmers agree that application logic should not be in the data model, so I am trying to understand how I could extract the logic of `validate` into a `@Service`, without destroying my generic approach (and without using something like `instanceof`!)

Is that possible?

Comment: Please provide more context, what does validate do? Can this also be achieved with Bean Validation?

Comment: @LeonardBrünings no, it's complex validation logic, so please just treat it as a method without side effects.

Comment: From the name validate it looks like it is not the application logic but a validation of the data in the class so current structure looks good to me.

Comment: @Rakesh I agree, but coding standards in the project do not allow for this structure and instead require me to build a pure data model...

Comment: are these classes supposed to be `@Service`s?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko No, they are supposed to be data models. I want to extract `validate` into a `@Service`.

Comment: @MarkusAppel why do they define business logic then?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko thats the question. I want to _extract_ the business logic.

Comment: @MarkusAppel the business logic has already been defined in these methods, what do you mean by "extracting"? calling? delegating calls to services?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Take the logic of  `validate`and put it into a `@Service`, so instead of calling `myClass.validate()` I can call `myValidationService.validate(myClass)`. This would all be trivial if it wasn't for the generic part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, found a solution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern

Effectively:

```
public abstract class MyClass {

   public abstract boolean validate();

}

public class MyClassImpl1 extends MyClass {

   ....

   public boolean validate(ValidatorService validator) {
      return validator.validate(this);
   }

}

public class MyClassImpl2 extends MyClass {

   ...

   public boolean validate(ValidatorService validator) {
      return validator.validate(this);
   }

}

@Service
public class ValidatorService {

   public boolean validate(MyClass myClass) {
      return myClass.validate(this);
   }

   public boolean validate(MyClassImpl1 myClassImpl1) {
      // Do something
      return false;
   }

   public boolean validate(MyClassImpl2 myClassImpl12) {
      // Do something else
      return false;
   }
}
```

And now you can call `validatorService.validate(myClass)` or `myClass.validate(validatorService)` wherever you `@Autowire ValidatorService validatorService`.